# Unable to pass variable in Informix

Tags: sql, informix, avaya

I was able to figure out how to get connected to Avaya CMS through Informix using SQL. The below query works but when I try to replace the ''1/01/19'' with a variable, I get the following error: "EIX000: (-1205) Invalid month in date"

Code that works

```
select * from Openquery(CMS, 'select * FROM dagent  WHERE ROW_DATE = ''1/01/19'' ');
```

Code that does not work

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = '2021-01-21'
select * from Openquery(CMS, 'select * FROM dagent WHERE ROW_DATE = ''+@startDate+'' ');
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: If the intent is to concatenate @startDate in the middle of the string before passing to Openquery, then you need three quotes in a row before and after `+`, not two.

Comment: @Fred When I tried that I get the following error: Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: Why declare @startDate as a DATETIME? In order to concatenate you would need to convert it to VARCHAR anyway.

Comment: Also, based on your example code this is a `sql-server` question, though the original error message was from `informix` because the value passed was literally `'+@startDate+'`

Comment: @Fred Thanks for your help. It was an informix issue.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is not enough single quotes.

You have:

```
'select * FROM dagent WHERE ROW_DATE = ''+@startDate+'' '
                                       ^^            ^^
```

In each case where you have two adjacent single quotes, you need a third too.  The two single quotes map to one single quote, so the quoted string contains `+@startDate+`, not the concatenation of your variable.

You need:

```
'select * FROM dagent WHERE ROW_DATE = '''+@startDate+''' '
```

Now the first two single quotes in the triplet map to a single quote; the third terminates the string, the `+@startDate+` becomes string concatenation, and then the next single quote starts a new string, the two single quotes map to one quote, and the space and single quote finish the string.

How to debug?

- Assign the string you used to a variable and print it.
- Assign the string I suggest to a variable and print it.